# Error, trying to plot a graph of solution to a Second Order ODE using Euler Method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, ode

I am doing a project, where I want to use Euler's Method to show a solution to this Second Order Different equation
`0=y''+y'+9.81y`

So I started by changing the second-order into a system of first-order equations
`y'=u, u'=f(t,y,u)`

With initial condition
`y(0)=180, u(0)=0`

So I get two equation in the end
`y[n + 1] = y[n] + u[n] * (t[n + 1] - t[n]), u[n + 1] = u[n] + f(u[0], y[n], t[0]) * (t[n + 1] - t[n])`

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def odeEuler(f, y0, u0, t):
    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    u = np.zeros(len(t))
    y[0] = y0
    u[0] = u0
    for n in range(0, len(t) - 1):
        y[n + 1] = y[n] + u[n] * (t[n + 1] - t[n])
        u[n + 1] = u[n] + f(u[0], y[n], t[0]) * (t[n + 1] - t[n])
    return y, u


t = np.linspace(0, 100)
y0 = 180
u0 = 0
f = lambda u, y, t: -9.81 * y - u
y = odeEuler(f, y0, u0, t)

plt.plot(t, y, 'b.-')
plt.legend(['Euler'])
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 200])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

However, when I run the code, it give me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/huangy15/PycharmProjects/Draft/Damped Driven Pendulum/Praying this works.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.plot(t, y, 'b.-')
  File "/Users/huangy15/PycharmProjects/Draft/Damped Driven Pendulum/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3021, in plot
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/huangy15/PycharmProjects/Draft/Damped Driven Pendulum/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/Users/huangy15/PycharmProjects/Draft/Damped Driven Pendulum/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/Users/huangy15/PycharmProjects/Draft/Damped Driven Pendulum/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (2, 50)
```

Can anyone help me check if my idea works, and if not, what other approaches I can take? Thanks!

Comment: There should be no index `0` in the Euler step, only `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `odeEuler` function is returning two variables: `y` and `u`, you need to select just one of them to plot.

Store the output of the function in two different variables will solve the problem:

```
y, u = odeEuler(f, y0, u0, t)
```

Comment: I got it to work, thank you for your help!